# speed of setter functions not what expected

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, jsperf

I am comparing the performance of two different types of setters as shown below:

```
var q={};
var z={};
(function(){
  var x=1;
  q.x=function(){
    return x;
  };
  q.x.set=function(val){
    x=val;
  };
})();
(function(){
  var x=1;
  z.x=function(){
    return x;
  };
  z.x_set=function(val){
    x=val;
  };
})();
```

The difference lies in where the setter is stored: `q.x.set` vs `z.x_set`. I expected the `z` variant to run faster since it requires one less table look-up. On the contrary the `q` variant is consistently faster. Any ideas why? Here is the jsperf: http://jsperf.com/hq7f3

Comment: I should add I am using chrome os.

Comment: For me, `q` is slower than `z` by ~25%, as expected.

Comment: @AlexWayne wow really? What browser?  There should be only a very minor difference if any.

Comment: @Pointy Chrome 38, OSX 10.9. It's in the results on the jsperf page. Which now also shows Chrome 36 giving a slight preference to `q`, which is odd. Honestly though, this stuff is so fast that I'm not sure these measurements matter. This difference will not be the performance issue in any large application.

Comment: Im on chrome 36 and I keep getting a preference for `q` by 10%-20%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your experiment now has a few results from various browsers.  Lets look at the results.

So we expect `z` to be faster than `q`. But when we examine the results we see two different categories of result.

1. Results are *nearly* identical, trending towards `q` being slightly faster.
2. **OR** `z` is a significantly faster.

What this tells me is that this is at the mercy of implementation details of various JS engines. Different JS engines use a ton of low level optimizations this change the timing characteristics of these very small atomic operations. Perhaps the `q` pattern triggers an optimization that `z` does not in some browsers. Or perhaps some browsers have an optimization for the `z` pattern that older browsers did not support. But given the lack of consistency, the *why* is very hard to answer.

One thing that is clear form the results so far, is that *on average* `z` is faster than `q`. Sometimes `q` is faster, but when `z` is faster, it's a lot faster.

[image: chart!]

---

But practically, the difference is negligible. This is a tiny operation. Tiny changes in a tiny operation can lead to large changes form a percentage perspective, but very very small changes to the performance profile in a larger application. Personally, I think this is academically interesting, but of little actual consequence.